For infinitive construction
why in the sentence
It is typical of the disease for it to start with an itchy rash
do we need "for it"?
For me it looks superfluous.

By the way, I would say, To me it looks superfluous.

Yes, I'd remove for it too:

It is typical of the disease to start with an itchy rash.

This resultant sentence can have its extraposition removed

To start with an itchy rash is typical of the disease.

and would be fine too.
Edit
As Kate said, the version with for it is perfectly idiomatic too.

It can be omitted, but the version with for it is perfectly idiomatic.

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.  Incorporated.

Thank you all! Your comments are of great help!

"for it" is not necessary but emphasizes that "start" there does not mean to initiate something but  to "begin".
If the itchy rash turned into burning, suppurating blisters, you could use "start out", as that phrase usually implies a subsequent change and also makes clear that the meaning is "begin" rather than "initiate":

It is typical of the disease  to start out with an itchy rash which turns into suppurating blisters after two or three days.

